# Graphql-codegen nested fragment use inside a React component

Tags: graphql-codegen

The nested fragment `regularUserResponseFragmentDocument`

```
import { graphql } from '../../generated/graphql';

export const regularErrorFragmentDocument = graphql(`
  fragment regularError on FieldError {
    field
    message
  }
`);

export const regularUserFragmentDocument = graphql(`
  fragment regularUser on User {
    id
    username
  }
`);

export const regularUserResponseFragmentDocument = graphql(`
  fragment regularUserResponse on UserResponse {
    errors {
      ...regularError
    }
    user {
      ...regularUser
    }
  }
`);
```

is used in a component like so:

```
if (response.data?.login) {
  const data = useFragment(regularUserResponseFragmentDocument, response.data.login);
  const errorsData = useFragment(regularErrorFragmentDocument, data.errors);
  if (errorsData) {
    setErrors(toErrorMap([...errorsData]));
  }
  const userData = useFragment(regularUserFragmentDocument, data.user);
  if (userData) {
    await router.push('/');
  }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid use of `useFragment` on the nested fragments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is not; this is the proper way to get nested masked fragments.
You will find a similar example here where `useFragment()` was renamed to `getFragmentData()` (from codegen config) to avoid React hooks rules issues: https://github.com/charlypoly/codegen-repros/blob/master/client-preset-nested-fragments-interface/src/App.tsx

Comment: Does this mean that `useFragment` is not an actual hook and can be called safely inside loops/conditionals?

Comment: Yes, I have also been confused by the name but they even mention that useFragment is not a hook on the page: https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/plugins/presets/preset-client

Comment: What's the actual point of these masked fragments ? The fragment data is actually present in the returned response, but the generated types don't expose the fragments data - only possible via accessor method. From the first sight looks like unnecessary complication

Comment: The point of masking is explained here: https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/plugins/presets/preset-client#embrace-fragment-masking-principles but I agree that it is complicating things. Luckily it can be disabled: https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/plugins/presets/preset-client#how-to-disable-fragment-masking

Comment: This answer should be quoted in the official docs when they speak about Fragments and Fragment masking. Thank you so much!