# Using keys with graphql fragment masking

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphql-codegen

As far as I know, fragment masking is considered a best practice when developing graphql clients, but I'm having some difficulties wrapping my head around how to write even some simple react necessities with that level of obscurity. One common necessity is providing `key` properties in iterations:

One example I'm working on is pulling repository data from Github to print cards with each of them. The query is:

```
fragment RepositoryCard on Repository {
  resourcePath
  description
}
```

Then, I'd use this query in a bigger one that request a user profile and gets some of their repositories:

```
    query GetUserData($login: String!) {
        user(login: $login) {
            bio
            name
            repositories(first: 10) {
                edges {
                    node {
                        ...RepositoryCard
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So far, so good. Then I'd map the responses to cards:

```
{
  data?.user?.repositories?.edges?.map((repository) => (
    <RepositoryCard 
      className="my-2"
      repositoryNode={repository?.node}
    />
  ))
}
```

But then, I need a `key` prop for this iteration. The best approach would be to use the `resourcePath` since that's unique. However, since fragment masking is used, `graphql-codegen` doesn't allow me to see the contents of the type of `repository.node`, so I can't access `resourcePath` from outside of the component to get it.

What's the common approach to solve this?

Comment: So far, the only way I've found to get this working is to `useFragment` inside the map. But obviously that's against the rules of hooks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like `useFragment` is not a real hook, so it isn't necessary to follow the rules of hooks. In an [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74302167/15768984) I see that the solution is to simply rename that function to something that won't trigger warnings (and better show the fact that it isn't a hook), so in your `codegen.ts`:

```js
  generates: {
    "./src/__generated__/": {
      preset: "client",
      plugins: [],
      presetConfig: {
        gqlTagName: "gql",
        fragmentMasking: {
          unmaskFunctionName: "getFragmentData",
        }
      }
    }
```

Then you can just call `getFragmentData` (previously `useFragment`) inside the `map` without getting any warnings:

```
data?.repositories?.edges?.filter((r) => !!(r?.node))
                          .map((r) => r?.node)
                          .map((repository) => {
                             const key = getFragmentData(REPOSITORY_CARD_FRAGMENT, repository)!.resourcePath;
                             return (
                                <RepositoryCard
                                   key={key}
                                   className="my-2"
                                   query={repository!}
                                 />
                              );
                           })
```